# wpforms: How do I query for the form description in custom smart tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've followed this tutorial: https://developers.wpforms.com/docs/create-a-custom-smart-tag/

How can I extract the form description form my custom smart tag "form_description"? Why isn't that included in the wpforms plugin in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this array `$form_data['settings']`, that holds this information :)

`$desc = (!empty($form_data['settings']['form_desc']) ? $form_data['settings']['form_desc'] : '';
$content = str_replace( '{form_description}', sanitize_text_field( $desc ), $content );`

Comment: I see you have answered your question or are you still trying to extract the form_description value?